# Создание экрана настроек в android приложении: делать свой экран или воспользоваться студийным?

Tags: android, android-preferences

На данный момент хочу сделать в приложении экран настроек. Пока есть только настройка изменения языка но думаю что чуть позже будут и другие настройки. Вот собственно у меня и возник вопрос - как будет лучше: создавать свою разметку, свои классы и все остальное для поддержки своего экрана настройки, или же создать все средствами android studio и получить на выходе все уже созданное автоматически.

Несколько дней тому я попробовал создать экран настроек в студии, но увиденное меня немного напрягло. Вроде все круто, создался красивый экран настроек где можно запарится и все настроить так как нужно, но сколько всего было создано для поддержки одного маленького экранчика. Я просмотрел все что было создано, и убедился что все нужно для нормального функционирования настроек. Но вот вопрос - стоит ли оно того? Как будет проще и правильнее? Да, моя лень говорит что нужно создавать в студии и не парится, ведь там уже все будет в комплекте, но с другой стороны не будет ли оно намного тяжелее кастомного экрана? Надеюсь я не первый кто задумался над созданием своего экрана настроек в приложении и я думаю что получу здесь дельный совет и информацию.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, к чему вообще этот вопрос. Тут вопрос только во времени и устраивает ли вас стандартный экран настроек. Вы сами выбираете что для вас удобнее. Если вы работаете в компании, то конечно вы пойдете по макетам, которые вам выдали дизайнеры и будете верстать сами. Может вам необходимо создать экран в зависимости от технологий, которые используется в компании (например Litho для создания макета из кода). Все зависит от вас

Comment: дело в том что мне макета не выдавали, все придумывается и сочиняется мною лично)) поэтому вопрос все-таки во времени больше получается)

Comment: Ну тогда оставляйте стандартный, отсекайте не нужны элементы

Comment: та я то тоже склоняюсь к этой мысли) но вот прикол в том, что очень много зависимостей в стандартном экране, и если одну не так настроить то может потом все посыпаться, я изучил класс который создается и там очень много того что я просто не могу понять для чего :)

Comment: Не надо бояться. После того, как удалите ненужный вам код, неиспользуемые зависимостри (импорты) станут серыми. Их тоже можно удалить.

Comment: та удалить то можно, но потом как обработать в фрагменте выбор функции? я просто сейчас все расчистил получил кучу ошибок но все-равно не смог обработать выбор настройки